# AWS Beanstalk s3 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to update a nodejs app and ruined my s3 server. Instead of updating properly from services -> elastic beanstalk, I deleted the .zip file on s3 and replaced it with a new one. I rebuilt  my beanstalk environment but nothing happened.

Comment: Could this be fixed by  deleting the s3 bucket and then rebuilding the beanstalk environment and uploading a new version? What can I do?

Comment: problem solved! The issue was that I had uploaded the whole zipped webapp inside a folder, so the aws server couldn't see the server.js (or app.js) file.